# Pandas divide one row by another and output to another row in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For a Dataframe such as:

```
      dt
                COL000  COL001
      STK_ID                
      Rowname1  2  2
      Rowname2  1  4
      Rowname3  1  1
```

What's the easiest way to append to the same data frame the result of dividing Row1 by Row2? i.e. the desired outcome is:

```
                COL000  COL001
      STK_ID                
      Rowname1  2  2
      Rowname2  1  4
      Rowname3  1  1
      Newrow    2  0.5
```

Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm slowly getting to grips with pandas from an R background.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code below will [create a new row](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) with index `d` which is formed from dividing rows `a` and `b`.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.loc['d'] = df.loc['a'] / df.loc['b']

print(df)
#      x    y
# a  1.0  4.0
# b  2.0  5.0
# c  3.0  6.0
# d  0.5  0.8
```

Answer (score 2):

in order to access the first two rows without caring about the index, you can use:

```
df.loc['newrow'] = df.iloc[0] / df.iloc[1]
```

then just follow @Ffisegydd's solution...

in addition, if you want to append multiple rows, use the `pd.DataFrame.append` function.

Comment: This will create a new column called 'newrow', not a row.

Comment: DAMMIT, forgot the `loc`. well, it's fixed now. the main point was to show how to access rows by number.

Answer (score 0):

pandas does all the work row by row. By including another element it also interprets you want a new column:

```
data['new_row_with_division'] = data['row_name1_values'] / data['row_name2_values']
```