# How do I divide two rows from a pandas DataFrame and store the result in a second DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to divide two rows from a first `DataFrame`, and store the result in a second `DataFrame`. I've based my attempts on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042883/pandas-divide-one-row-by-another-and-output-to-another-row-in-the-same-dataframe), but so far haven't had any luck getting it to work.

The row indices in the first `DataFrame` are `tuples` of the format `(str, int)`, the ratios that I want to calculate (and to be the indices of the second `DataFrame`) are represented as a `tuple` of `tuples`, and are stored in a `list`:

```
(gene, position)
((gene, position1), (gene, position2))
```

My here's the code I have so far:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9], 'D' [10,11,12]}, 
                   index=[('geneA', 1538), ('geneA', 1591), ('geneA', 1687)])

               A  B  C   D
(geneA, 1538)  1  4  7  10
(geneA, 1591)  2  5  8  11
(geneA, 1687)  3  6  9  12

pairs = [(('geneA', 1538), ('geneA', 1591))]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for pair in pairs:
    df2.loc[[pair]] = df1.loc[[pair[0]]] / df1.loc[[pair[1]]]
```

When I run this code I get a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 3)
```

The previous example that I linked above doesn't have the nested brackets in the line that does the division, but when I remove the brackets I get `KeyErrors` related to the index. I suspect that this has something to do with my use of `tuples` and nested `tuples` as `indices`. Any help would be appreciated, I've spent the entire afternoon trying to figure this out.

Comment: Pairs looks to be an array with one element, which is a 2-tuple of 2-tuples.  You probably want it to be an array with two elements, each a 2-tuple.  Try:  pairs = [('geneA', 1538), ('geneA', 1591)].  There may be other issues though

Comment: You're missing a colon after 'D' in your DataFrame definition as well

Comment: The 'D:' was correct in my script, but got erased somehow when I was formatting the question, Thanks!

Comment: Also, in my full script, pairs will be a list with multiple 2-tuples of 2-tuples since it defines comparisons between two positions in the same gene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` uses `tuples for a`MultiIndex` ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object)):

> The `MultiIndex` object is the hierarchical analogue of the standard `Index` object which typically stores the axis labels in pandas objects. You can think of `MultiIndex` an **array of tuples** where each tuple is unique. A `MultiIndex` can be created from a list of arrays (using `MultiIndex.from_arrays`), an array of tuples (using `MultiIndex.from_tuples`), or a crossed set of iterables (using `MultiIndex.from_product`).

So it's probably most suitable to define a `MultiIndex` in the first place.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9], 'D': [10,11,12]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('geneA', 1538), ('geneA', 1591), ('geneA', 1687)]))

            A  B  C   D
geneA 1538  1  4  7  10
      1591  2  5  8  11
      1687  3  6  9  12
```

Defined like this, the division works fine:

```
pairs = [(('geneA', 1538), ('geneA', 1591))]
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for pair in pairs:
    df2[pair] = df1.loc[pair[0]].div(df1.loc[pair[1]])

df2.T

                                  A    B      C         D
((geneA, 1538), (geneA, 1591))  0.5  0.8  0.875  0.909091
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. This is literally the first script I've written that uses pandas, so I wasn't aware of MultiIndex. Seems very useful.